# CakePHP redirecting from one controller to another controller

Tags: php, url, redirect, cakephp

In cakephp folder, I have one controller SystemsController in one file(Admin) and another controller called UserController out of the admin file. how to redirect from SystemController to UserController?

Comment: which cakePHP version used?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CakePHP 3 you can set redirect after POST submit like this:

```
return $this->redirect(
            ['controller' => 'Orders', 'action' => 'thanks']
        );
```

If you are using Admin (or another) prefix just add before controller `'prefix' => 'Admin'`

If you want to redirect user after click on some button, use HtmlHelper

```
$this->Html->link('Magic Button', ['controller' => 'YourController', 'action' => 'YourAction'];
```

And eventually set prefix.

More: 
[Controllers - Redirecting to Other Pages](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages)
[Html Helper - Create Links](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/html.html#creating-links)
[Request & Response Objects - Request Parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-parameters)